# Is this sentence correct? How should I frame it?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, causative-have

Why does every guy has to / have to say that or use that sentence?
Should I use has or have? I can't really figure out the singular or plural.

Comment: Do you know how to write a question in the third person? Follow that rule.

Comment: Google **singular plural after every**. https://www.grammar.cl/english/all-every-each.htm